# Rails3 cannot save 'ñ' to Oracle 11g

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, activerecord, oracle11g

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3 and Oracle 11g. When saving a record in the DB with a character like 'ñ' I get the error below:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError:
U+00F1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII: INSERT INTO "OMNIAUTH_USERS" ("CREATED_AT",
"FIRST_NAME", "ID", "LAST_NAME", "STATUS", "UID", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:a1,
:a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7)):
app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

I tried to run this query to see the language used by Oracle:

```
SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL
```

It returned AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8.

These are my gems for Oracle:

```
gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.1.5'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.2'
gem 'ruby-plsql', '~> 0.5.0'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish two different nls settings

- the external one - defined by the environment variable NLS_LANG in you application. This determines your internal string representation when you send data to OCI client library.
- the internal one. It is the character set used by Oracle to store your data on disk.

Try to execute

```
select r.module, t.*
from v$sesssion_connection_info t
join v$session r on (r.sid = t.sid and t.serial# = r.serial#)
where r.sid = <your ruby connection SID>;

select * from nls_database_parameters;
select * from nls_instance_parameters;
```

If it shows, that you are using something like US7ASCII or ISO8859P1 then Oracle accepts your character and converts it into target character set(either by removing an accent or by replacing with '?').