# Wrong String encoding using JDBC Oracle Thin driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, encoding

I am using an Oracle database with ISO-8859-1 data.
When I try to get String from this DB using ResultSet and print result to console, I get a wrong encoding output.

```
Locale.getDefault(); // -> fr_FR
Charset.defaultCharset(); // -> UTF-8
```

But I tried to print these data from my `ResultSet` :

```
rs.getString("MY_COL"); // direct from ResultSet
new String(rs.getString("MY_COL").getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15")), Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // convert ISO bytes to UTF-8 bytes
```

This output :

```
gÃ©nÃ©rale
générale
```

So, why Oracle JDBC driver create String with ISO-8859-1 bytes encoding ?
How can I get String with UTF-8 bytes encoding without altering database (nor converting String) ?
Can I change it from the driver configuration ou JMV args ?

Comment: It is also possible that the string is stored incorrectly inside the database.

Comment: How can I verify that ?

Comment: Check the value in SQL*plus, toad or another tool?

Comment: Execute following select `select dump(my_col) from my_table` to get the bytes stored in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18080993/836215 - check databases internal encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your database is not in ISO 8859-1 (NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8ISO8859P1).

On the database

```
create table foo (col1 varchar2(40));
insert into foo values('é');
insert into foo values(chr(233));
select dump(col1) from foo;
```

should return

```
Typ=1 Len=1: 233 
Typ=1 Len=1: 233
```

If you get for example

```
Typ=1 Len=2: 195,169
Typ=1 Len=1: 233
```

then your database is set up for UTF8 (NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8).

Comment: I get the second output. So NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8 but my NLS_LANG is french_france.WE8ISO8859P1